# Use of two Dir VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 29 files that I need to continually update. All of these files are in the same folder.
I have another folder with 29 excel files (these files are extracted every week). All these files are in the same folder (folder 2)
For each Excel file to be updated, I need to search the Excel file that has the same name, in the folder 2, copy the worksheet ("Sheet 1") in my Excel file to be updated.
Below is my code.
When I run the code, I get a message "Runtime Error # 5"
Thank you for your help

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ChoixRep()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim Reps As String
Dim Repi As String

MsgBox "Choisir le dossier des fichiers de suivi DD"
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'création d'une boite de dialogue choix de répertoire
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False 'on ne peut choisir qu'un seul repertoire
    If fd.Show = -1 Then 'l'utilisateur à valider sa selection
        Reps = fd.SelectedItems(1) 'le repertoire choisi
        'Boucle repertoire
    End If

MsgBox "Choisir le reportoire des fichiers à importer"

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'création d'une boite de dialogue choix de répertoire
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False 'on ne peut choisir qu'un seul repertoire
    If fd.Show = -1 Then 'l'utilisateur à valider sa selection
        Repi = fd.SelectedItems(1) 'le repertoire choisi
    End If
doubleboucle Reps, Repi
End Sub

Private Sub doubleboucle(ByVal Reps As String, Repi As String)

Dim FichierS As String
Dim FichierI As String
Dim Ws As Workbook
Dim Wi As Workbook

FichierS = Dir(Reps & "\*.xls") 'je pense qu'on peut enlever .xls
FichierI = Dir(Repi & "\*.xls") 'je pense qu'on peut enlever .xls

Do While FichierS <> ""
    Set Ws = Workbooks.Open(Reps & "\" & FichierS)
        Do While FichierI <> ""
            Set Wi = Workbooks.Open(Repi & "\" & FichierI)
            If Ws.Name = Wi.Name Then
                Traitement Ws, Wi
            End If
            Wi.Save
            Wi.Close
            FichierI = Dir
        Loop
    Ws.Save
    Ws.Close
    FichierS = Dir
Loop

End Sub

Private Sub Traitement(ByRef Ws As Workbook, Wi As Workbook)

Wi.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells.Copy Ws.Add.Range("A1")
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Pour eviter d'avoir le message du presse papier à garder

End Sub
```

Comment: If the file has the same name in both directories, why do you need two `Dir`s?  Once you know the name in one directory, you automatically know the name in the other directory.

Comment: @YowE3K So I can use one Dir and keep the definition of Ws and Wi like that ? Thank you for your response

Comment: You set variables `Reps` and `Repi` inside `If`. If conditions fail, then you don't set them anywhere else and at the end you use them in a `doubleboucle` function. This might cause error.

Comment: @YowE3K  It works, thank you :). Another question : If the file hadn't the same name. Could I use two Dir with using <Find LookIn> to find for each file in folder 1 the file to import in folder 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need to have one `Dir` if the filenames in the two directories are identical.  (Because, once you know one filename, you also know the corresponding filename in the other directory - it's the same.)

You will, however, have problems because Excel can't have two workbooks open at the same time if they have the same filename - you will need to either:

- temporarily give them different names (as I do in the code below) or
- do all the processing in one file first, then close it and open the other one, and then do all the processing in that file.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ChoixRep()

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim Reps As String
    Dim Repi As String

    MsgBox "Choisir le dossier des fichiers de suivi DD"
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'création d'une boite de dialogue choix de répertoire
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False 'on ne peut choisir qu'un seul repertoire
    If fd.Show = -1 Then 'l'utilisateur à valider sa selection
        Reps = fd.SelectedItems(1) 'le repertoire choisi
        'Boucle repertoire
    End If

    MsgBox "Choisir le reportoire des fichiers à importer"

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'création d'une boite de dialogue choix de répertoire
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False 'on ne peut choisir qu'un seul repertoire
    If fd.Show = -1 Then 'l'utilisateur à valider sa selection
        Repi = fd.SelectedItems(1) 'le repertoire choisi
    End If
    doubleboucle Reps, Repi
End Sub

Private Sub doubleboucle(ByVal Reps As String, Repi As String)

    Dim Fichier As String
    Dim Ws As Workbook
    Dim Wi As Workbook

    Fichier = Dir(Reps & "\*.xls") 'je pense qu'on peut enlever .xls

    Do While Fichier <> ""
        'Create a dummy copy of one of the files
        FileCopy Repi & "\" & Fichier, Repi & "\DUMMY_" & Fichier
        'open the two files
        Set Wi = Workbooks.Open(Repi & "\DUMMY_" & Fichier)
        Set Ws = Workbooks.Open(Reps & "\" & Fichier)
        'process
        Traitement Ws, Wi
        'Save and close the changed workbook
        Ws.Save
        Ws.Close
        'close the unchanged workbook
        Wi.Close False 'Don't save changes (nothing was changed)
        'kill the dummy file
        Kill Repi & "\DUMMY_" & Fichier
        'Look for the next file to process
        Fichier = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub Traitement(ByRef Ws As Workbook, Wi As Workbook)
    'Note: "Ws.Add" won't work as a Workbook does not have an Add method.
    '      I changed it to be "Ws.Worksheets.Add" on the assumption that you are
    '      trying to create a new worksheet.
    Wi.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells.Copy Ws.Worksheets.Add.Range("A1")
    ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Pour eviter d'avoir le message du presse papier à garder

End Sub
```

---

The code below handles the case where the files are named `"extract_xxx_date.xls"` in the `Repi` directory, but named `"Suivi_xxx_MM.xls"` in the `Reps` directory:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ChoixRep()

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim Reps As String
    Dim Repi As String

    MsgBox "Choisir le dossier des fichiers de suivi DD"
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'création d'une boite de dialogue choix de répertoire
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False 'on ne peut choisir qu'un seul repertoire
    If fd.Show = -1 Then 'l'utilisateur à valider sa selection
        Reps = fd.SelectedItems(1) 'le repertoire choisi
        'Boucle repertoire
    End If

    MsgBox "Choisir le reportoire des fichiers à importer"

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'création d'une boite de dialogue choix de répertoire
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False 'on ne peut choisir qu'un seul repertoire
    If fd.Show = -1 Then 'l'utilisateur à valider sa selection
        Repi = fd.SelectedItems(1) 'le repertoire choisi
    End If
    doubleboucle Reps, Repi
End Sub

Private Sub doubleboucle(ByVal Reps As String, Repi As String)

    Dim FichierI As String
    Dim FichierS As String
    Dim Ws As Workbook
    Dim Wi As Workbook

    FichierS = Dir(Reps & "\*.xls") 'je pense qu'on peut enlever .xls

    Do While FichierS <> ""
        'Generate name of file in Repi directory
        FichierI = "extract_" & Split(FichierS, "_")(1) & "_date.xls"
        'open the two files
        Set Wi = Workbooks.Open(Repi & "\" & FichierI)
        Set Ws = Workbooks.Open(Reps & "\" & FichierS)
        'process
        Traitement Ws, Wi
        'Save and close the changed workbook
        Ws.Save
        Ws.Close
        'close the unchanged workbook
        Wi.Close False 'Don't save changes (nothing was changed)

        'Look for the next file to process
        FichierS = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub Traitement(ByRef Ws As Workbook, Wi As Workbook)
    'Note: "Ws.Add" won't work as a Workbook does not have an Add method.
    '      I changed it to be "Ws.Worksheets.Add" on the assumption that you are
    '      trying to create a new worksheet.
    Wi.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells.Copy Ws.Worksheets.Add.Range("A1")
    ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Pour eviter d'avoir le message du presse papier à garder

End Sub
```

Comment: It works, thank you :). Another question : If the file hadn't the same name. Could I use two Dir with using <Find LookIn> to find for each file in folder 1 the file to import in folder 2 ?

Comment: If the files don't have the same name, how do you determine that "file1.xls" in one directory is associated with "filexyz.xls" in another directory.  You mention <Find LookIn> which makes me think there is some text **within** the file that you actually match on.  (But, no, you can't use two `Dir`s **at the one time** - you would have to restructure the code to do one `Dir` first, saving the list of filenames to an array of some sort, and then do the next `Dir` after that.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Exactly there is some text in the file's name To match on. Ok I'll try to write  with two different Dir (no idea yet ;)).

Comment: If there is text **in the file's name** (e.g. "file1.xls" matches "filenew1.xls" and "file2.xls" matches "filenew2.xls", etc) then that is easily handled - just let us know what the rules are to decide what matches and what doesn't.

Comment: It's exactly that. The name of the file will be like your example.

Comment: @M.Ismael If you can give a specific example of what a filename is in `Repi` and what the corresponding filename is in `Reps`, I can supply you with code to process that.  But "like your example" isn't sufficient to write code.

Comment: You're right. Each file is link to a city. Each file name contain the abréviation of the city name (3 words exactly). File in Repi extract_nts_date and the correspondant in Reps is Suivi_nts_MM (nts is the abréviation of the city name in this case).

Comment: @M.Ismael I have updated the answer based on your last comment.  (But I'm worried that `extract_nts_date` might not be specific, and you might really mean something like `extract_nts_20170829`.)

Comment: yeah I put date because it will be updated (it's the extract date). Thank you for the update. I look at it and give you an answer. Thanks again

Comment: Maybe `"_date.xls"` can be replaced with `"_" & Format(Now, "whatever_date_format_you_use") & ".xls"`

Comment: Hello thank you the code works. Your suggestions were pretty good. I don't have to use Two Dir :) .... Thank you again and have a nice day